# Energy & performance comparison: GPU mining vs playing HD Video

Tags: mining-hardware, hashpower, gpu

Using the built-in ATI video card on my computer, I can mine at about a 30-50 MHps rate. I'm wondering, how does this amount of work compare to normal video card operation? Or how can it be calculated? Is mining for 6 hours at this rate equivalent to watching Transformers 2 in HD over and over again on my monitor?

There's already plenty of questions about equipment wear when GPU mining, I'm looking for an easy-to-understand comparison to normal GPU taks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using a GPU to mine Bitcoins would use a lot more power than watching HD video, since while the video decoder would only use the processing power it needed, a Bitcoin mine would use all of the power available to it.

I don't have any real numbers, but I think mining Bitcoins would be equivalent to, say, playing Far Cry 3 on the maximum settings, while watching HD video would be more like playing Fallout 3 on medium settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how much work your video card is doing during various tasks with [GPU Caps Viewer](http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/).  It will tell you what clock speed your card is running at, what the max it is capable of, and what percentage of your GPU is being used.